# Visual Studio : how to embed app.config in the exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a program which compile and works fine and uses this `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

When compiling the program it give me two files `myapp.exe` and `myapp.exe.config`. When starting the program if `myapp.exe.config` is missing the start will fail and an exception will be thrown

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

Is there any way to include the config file in the application as a resource so I got only `myapp.exe` as an output?

Comment: The config file is always generated unless YOU changed something to stop that behavior. There are other ways to get to variables, but why would the config file be missing?

Comment: I delete it as a part of my tests to check all possible defects. And i want to ensure that my application doesn't fail in running because of this issue.

Comment: Like the doctor told the man who said 'Doc, it hurts when I go like this.' and the man tries to scratch the middle of his back. Doctor 'Don't do that. That will be $150.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy at runtime](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/), the following codes are taken directly from that link. This helper class

```
public static class RuntimePolicyHelper
{
    public static bool LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully { get; private set; }

    static RuntimePolicyHelper()
    {
        ICLRRuntimeInfo clrRuntimeInfo =
            (ICLRRuntimeInfo)RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject(
                Guid.Empty, 
                typeof(ICLRRuntimeInfo).GUID);
        try
        {
            clrRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // This occurs with an HRESULT meaning 
            // "A different runtime was already bound to the legacy CLR version 2 activation policy."
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = false;
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("BD39D1D2-BA2F-486A-89B0-B4B0CB466891")]
    private interface ICLRRuntimeInfo
    {
        void xGetVersionString();
        void xGetRuntimeDirectory();
        void xIsLoaded();
        void xIsLoadable();
        void xLoadErrorString();
        void xLoadLibrary();
        void xGetProcAddress();
        void xGetInterface();
        void xSetDefaultStartupFlags();
        void xGetDefaultStartupFlags();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
    }
}
```

will automatically setup on runtime, you can verify if RuntimePolicyHelper.LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully is true and handle the error otherwise.